# Display problem multiplying matrix

Tags: matrix, display

I'm multiplying matrices and **I don't get answer I want**  I just get matrix `M` times matrix `N`, there is no result. 
What to do and what to fix in order to get result displayed?

```
M = {{1, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}} // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
P = {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 6, 4}, {5, 9, 5}} // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
M.P
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You need to include more detail of what you are doing.  Possibly using `Dot` (short form `.`) will solve your problem if you have actual matrix data.  The data might potentially need to be transposed.  Also you can/should not use `N` as a variable as it is already a defined System function.

Comment: Printscreen: http://postimg.org/image/qgo5cqz3t/

Comment: @VladimirS, This is not a good way to share your code, see the edits I did for you.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks, I'll learn how to do that for my next question.

Comment: The problem is `MatrixForm`.  See, detail *is* important. :-)  I am closing this question as a duplicate. (A link will be inserted at the top of your post.)  See the answers there fore a full explanation.

Comment: Please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Read how to do the formatting of you code [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: Oh, Matrixform... Ok then. Thanks a lot. Bye

Answer (score 2):

```
M = {{1, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}
> ```

```
P = {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 6, 4}, {5, 9, 5}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 6, 4}, {5, 9, 5}}
> ```

```
M.P
```

> ```
> {{25, 47, 33}, {35, 66, 54}, {45, 85, 75}}
> ```

Or, if you want the nice display be sure not to include that in the definition of your matrix

```
MatrixForm[M = {{1, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]